# VC++ link external library (interface to dll)

Tags: visual-c++, hyperlink

I am new to C++ in windows and am trying to write a simple Win32 colsole application which makes just one api call to an external library.

This external library is a .lib file which I believe acts an interface to a DLL.

I did the following after looking at other posts :-

1. add library/headers in vc++ project
2. add library to link options
3. Copied the dll to windows\system32 directory just in case.

and tried to compile, but I get the error below.

1>AnyFirewallEngineCInterfaceToDll.lib(AnyFirewallEngine.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl EyeballGetModule_AnyFirewall(void)" (?EyeballGetModule_AnyFirewall@@YAJXZ)

The funny thing is that the function with the error does not seem to be in the header file, so I believe it may be in the DLL.

My console app just has 1 line :- a call to function af_init();

Any ideas on what else I could try ?

Comment: The lib you are linking looks like a static library, not an import library for the DLL.  You have to go back to the author or vendor of this library and ask for the correct library or proper linking instructions.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was wrong and perhaps the library is meant to be static. I did a dumpbin.exe on the library and it says File type : LIBRARY. I also tried compinling the souce as C (as opposed to c++) and messing around with the stdcall vs cdecl calling method but no luck. Unfortunately the SDK docs simplay say that this should work with VS2010 and that in order to use C I should use the library AnyFirewallEngineCInterfacetoDLL so I just assumed by the name that it may indeed be an import library.

Comment: dumpbin /all shows _af_init as one of the public symbols, so I think there must be some problem with the way I am linking ?

Comment: Looks like the .lib is trying to call the DLL file as the function call the linker is complaining about is indeed found in the DLL ! So I just need to figure out how to tell the linker that what its looking for is in the DLL